# Decrypt SCTP-DTLS Traffic in WebRTC in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, encryption, webrtc, sctp, dtls

I'm trying to inspect the pakets sent over the sctp connection of webrtc datachannels in chrome on my local machine. There isnt really much information which I found about decrypting DTLS-Traffic (e.g. through wireshark). Is there a way to access  the certificate generated for the peerconnection? If not, how would one decrypt the traffic by other means? (e.g. some mitm proxy, mostly those are for TLS only though).

Answer (score 1):

the certificate alone won't help, Chrome typically uses DTLS with perfect forward secrecy.

The --disable-webrtc-encryption (see http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) might work in canary.

Comment: From what I am seeing is that this flag only disables RTP Media Encryption (thus mediachannels) and not datachannels